# Jboss-cli: JBAS014653 ("Expected [OBJECT] but was LIST") when trying to add datasource

Tags: postgresql, jboss, wildfly, xa, jboss-cli

I tried inserting a new XA-Datasource in Wildfly 8.1:

`/opt/wildfly/bin/jboss-cli.sh --connect --controller=192.168.1.220:9990`

`[standalone@192.168.1.220:9990 /] xa-data-source add --name=myName --jndi-name=java:jboss/datasources/myDS --driver-name=postgresql --user-name=myUser --password=myPass --use-java-context=true --use-ccm=true --min-pool-size=10 --max-pool-size=100 --transaction-isolation=TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED --pool-prefill=true --allocation-retry=1 --prepared-statements-cache-size=32 --share-prepared-statements=true --xa-datasource-class=org.postgresql.xa.PGXADataSource --xa-datasource-properties=[{ServerName=192.168.1.220},{PortNumber=5432},{DatabaseName=postgres}] --valid-connection-checker-class-name=org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.postgres.PostgreSQLValidConnectionChecker --exception-sorter-properties=org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.postgres.PostgreSQLExceptionSorter`

But I received this error:

`{"JBAS014653: Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {"Operation step-1" => "JBAS014688: Wrong type for exception-sorter-properties. Expected [OBJECT] but was LIST"}}`

In the Web interface the value for `Exception Sorter` is a simple string.

I tried many value types.

Comment: To make the question easier to find and answer, I added the tags xa and jboss-cli in exchange for java, along with adding more detail to the title. I also improved the question formatting and grammar to make it a bit easier to follow. However, you may still need to indicate just what sorts of values you tried for Exception Sorter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `--exception-sorter-class-name=org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.postgres.PostgreSQLExceptionSorter` instead of `--exception-sorter-properties=org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.postgres.PostgreSQLExceptionSorter`.